# how to implement use of join() method in titanium?

Tags: javascript

I am developing android app in titanium studio, my question how to join array of elements separated by comma.
I used like

```
temp = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };
var string_temp = temp.join();
```

but it is not working any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is an object not an array. `temp` should be `["a", "b", "c", ....]`

Comment: Not look like an object also :)